# suggestion box in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

anyone know how to create a suggestion box in ruby on rails? all the materials i found so far are about observe some text field and update some list in other , not related to suggestion box...

Thanks!

Comment: i mean the one like google search, you input some keywords or characters, it show a list of suggestion related to your keywords..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ruby on rails I would suggest you to use auto_complete plugin, I have written two blogs on auto complete, please check [here](http://www.spritle.com/blogs/?p=395).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery plugin, like this one:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Demo here:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/